# How to make a twitch application to work with discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, twitch, twitch-api

Im trying to make a very simple discord bot in python too send a message to channel whenever a twitch channel goes live but i dont know how to make proper twitch apllication.

Comment: This reads like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276284/how-can-i-create-a-discord-bot-that-will-send-out-notifications-about-streams which I answered with a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be better off using webhooks. I never tried it before but I find this guide : https://gist.github.com/smiley/78c1c2a57d17a179a978a1438b389710

Also, here is more information about webhooks : https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks